# What is the default password Jitterbit?

Tags: passwords, jitterbit

For some time I try to use Jitterbit, but do not have a password, someone could inform me. 
I need it to log in Jitterbit Server.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default password for Jitterbit is blank. If your are unable to login, you can also reset the password to default by running the below query in PostgeSQL database which is installed alongwith Jitterbit.
The connection credentials of PostgreSQL db is stored in jitterbit.conf file located in your installation path under [DbInfo] section.

Run the below query by changing the db to TranDb

```
UPDATE UsersTab SET Password='d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' WHERE User_Id = 0
```

Now you can connect to Jitterbit Studio using Username: Admin and password as blank